# How to put an ImageView relative to a background image in Android Studio

Tags: android, background, imageview, android-relativelayout

For my GUI i use the RelativeLayout and want to keep it as it is the best for different screeen resolutions.

For example i have this Background, where i want to put an ImageView exactly over the TV-screen (to show some pictures on the TV).

I want this to work in different screen resolutions.

How can i achieve this? Or is this even possible? Examples are welcome :)

My Background Image:
[image]

Comment: Check out PorterDuff modes

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would separate the TV image from the background and make it a new ImageView. Then you can set the position of TV-Screen ImageView regarding to the TV ImageView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about that but my real background image is complexer than in my question.

There are people sitting in front of the TV and other stuff arround
Something like this:
http://imgur.com/vpqIgcP

I think this wont work out quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you can try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/back"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"></RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/back"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/back"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

But i think there could be an issue with different resolution try this and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your TV as a PNG. Carve out the screen from this image. This will make the TV image TRANSPARENT for the screen(red outlined portion)

Next, your images/screen-slides must be exactly same as the TV image in terms of width and height. However, the actual content of the image/screen-slides must only be in the hollow portion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured out how to do this.

At first i changed the background-picture from a Layout-Background to an ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/background1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Then i can set the TV-image relative to the Background-ImageView's f.e. top and right margin. (looks hardcoded like this)

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/tvImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="169dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="169dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Basically there are now two things i have handle, to make the TV-image fit when changing the screen resolution:

**1) the width and height of the picture.**

**2) the position of the picture.**

**To find out 1):**

My Background is f.e. 500x250dp.
In an Image program i measured the size i need for the TV-image: 125x85dp.
Now i can calculate the width and height back depending on the background size.

500/125 = 4 for width calculation

250/85 = 2,9 for height calculation

So if the Screen changes for example to 800x400dp the width and height for the TV-image an be calculated like this:

800 / 4 = 200dp

400 / 2,9 = 137dp

So my TV-image should have a size of 200x137

**To find out 2)**

Again i have to calculate like in Point 1). Find out the position of the TV-screen and then set the layout margins according to the calcualtions. I havent implemented this point yet, so i can't explain more, but i think you get what i want to say. If not feel free to ask :)

And in the end, i can setup the TV-image with this code (hardcoded values should be the calculated variables!)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPar = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tvImage.getLayoutParams();
    layoutPar.setMargins(0,88,210,0); // or whatever
    layoutPar.height = 137;
    layoutPar.width = 250;
    tvImage.setLayoutParams(layoutPar);
```